# In Elm, how to decode a JSON object inside nested JSON

Tags: json, pipeline, elm, hateoas, decoder

I use Elm **0.19.1** with NoRedInk/**elm-json-decode-pipeline**/1.0.0

I have an Aircraft type which is

```
type alias Aircraft = {name:String}
```

For this, I have the following decoder:

```
aircraftDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder Aircraft        
aircraftDecoder =            
    Json.Decode.succeed Aircraft            
    |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.required "name" Json.Decode.string
```

Unfortunately, the decoder is complaining me telling: **"BadBody "Problem with the given value: (...)"**
This is because actually my area of interest if full of noise around it (from an HATEOAS api), like this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "aircrafts" : [ {
      "name" : "AC01",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/aircrafts/1"
        },
        "aircraft" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/aircrafts/1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "AC01",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/aircrafts/2"
        },
        "aircraft" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/aircrafts/2"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/aircrafts{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/aircrafts"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 4,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

How can I change the code, and **keep using the Pipeline**, so that the decoder doesn't get lost by all this noise?

I heard something about using Json.Decode.at, but the documentation is not good enough to let me get the correct code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problem is that:

1. at this moment, your decoder might be well fit to decode a single `Aircraft`
2. however, your JSON has a list of `Aircraft`s
3. also, you decoder does not know where, in the JSON, it might find `Aircraft`s

And you know, for Elm `Aircraft` and `List Aircraft` are completely different beats (as they should be). Anyway, the solution would be a two-step thing:

1. Telling the decoder where, within the JSON structure, are the `Aircraft`s
2. Parse a `List Aircraft` instead of a single `Aircraft`

Following your code and importing `at` and `list` from `Json.Decode`, the code might look like that:

```
listAircraftDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder List Aircraft 
listAircraftDecoder =
    at ["_embedded", "aircrafts"] (list aircraftDecoder)
```

This means we're now aiming at a list of `Aircraft`s and that this list is an array within the JSON. Starting at the JSON root, take the property `"_embedded"` and, inside it, the property `"aircrafts"`. This is a array, and Elm's `list` knows how to deal with it.

Finally, we just need to tell Elm's `list` to pass each element of the JSON array to a specific decoder – your `aircraftDecoder` in our case.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Very nice!! It means that if _embedded itself was inside _noise, which in turn was inside _root, I should have used
at ["_root", "_noise", "_embedded", "aircrafts"] (list aircraftDecoder)? This is, I have to puth the whole path from root until target?

Comment: Yep, you've got it!

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
aircraftNameDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder String
aircraftNameDecoder =
    Json.Decode.map (Maybe.withDefault "" << List.head) <|
        Json.Decode.at [ "_embedded", "aircrafts" ] <|
            Json.Decode.list (Json.Decode.field "name" Json.Decode.string)


aircraftDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder Aircraft
aircraftDecoder =
    Json.Decode.succeed Aircraft
        |> Json.Decode.Pipeline.custom aircraftNameDecoder
```

And please see [elm/json](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#at) for more documentation on `Json.Decode.at`.

Comment: Hi simplystuart, what is the purpose of
Json.Decode.map (Maybe.withDefault "" << List.head)
?

Comment: As far as I understood, his solution is to allow you to decode only the first aircraft (List.head), which might be your case ; )

Comment: In your object above "aircrafts" is an array, so that Json.Decode.map line converts a list of aircraft names to a single aircraft name. @cuducos is right, I assumed that was your case based on the Aircraft type.